What is the origin and meaning of the phrase “wear the brown helmet”?
I have heard the phrase “to wear the brown helmet” in a few conversations, twice in old television shows (I cannot recall the names), and in occasional online comments. I have a notion as to the meaning but am curious as to its origin and if there is any specific meaning available.

Is that like “Wear the fox hat”?

From a 2011 book by Alan Axelrod:  The Cheaper the Crook, the Gaudier the Patter: Forgotten Hipster Lines, Tough Guy Talk, and Jive Gems
It seems the expression wear the brown helmet is derived from the 1930s "win the porcelain helmet”.
[emphasis not mine]

Win the porcelain helmet (or hairnet)—Receive something useless or of highly dubious value. Heard chiefly during the 1930s, with variants including win the barbwire garter and win the fur-lined bathtub. To wear a porcelain helmet may also suggest getting something worse than useless, such as a toilet for a hat. One of the characters on the police drama Hill Street Blues, which aired on NBC from 1981 to 1987, an uptight SWAT commander, characterized the embarrassment of failure as  wearing the brown helmet, which may well have been a variant of the 1930s expression.

The groundbreaking TV series Hill Street Blues used the expression a "brown helmet", meaning to earn something of useless value, twice:

1981 “Not to belabor the point, but I can't help thinking...that a call from you to commander Swanson might be in order. I can't help feeling we're being fitted for a brown helmet on this one, Francis.”

1983 “Seriously though, Frank, I doubt there is a captain in the entire department... who could have a direct order to his men publicly countermanded by the chief...and handle it as well as you have. You may have been handed the brown helmet, squire, but you sure wear it like a goldarn party hat.”


Searching the Internet, among the earliest references I found of porcelain hairnet were from a Dictionary of American Slang by Harold Wentworth, the 1975 edition also includes the variants “win the tinfoil doorknob”, “win the cast-iron overshoes” and “win the solid gold chamber pot”;   a Time article  printed in 1996: “You need this like you need a porcelain hairnet. Go west, young man. Go north. Don't give your life to them. Get out of town.”
And from 1998, an American cartoon show called Arthur in Binky Rules/Meet Binky (season 4).

Buster Baxter: Listen, Pinky Crooker: this evidence stuff is a wet smack. All you're gonna do is win the porcelain hairnet.
Fern Walters: Am I supposed to understand what you're saying?


The TV series is Arthur; "Binky Rules / Meet Binky" is the title of the episode.

Isn't brown referring to the colour of the sh*t that has been/will be dropped on you?

@NL_Derek  It said as much by … something worse than useless, such as a toilet for a hat..

As Mari-Lou A indicates in her answer, "win the porcelain hairnet" has been around since at least the early 1960s, and "porcelain hairnet" since at least the mid-1930s. From Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, Dictionary of American Slang, first edition (1961):

win the porcelain hairnet | win the fur-lined bathtub | win the tinfoil doorknob | win the cast-iron overshoes | win the barbwire garter | win the solid gold chamber pot Phrases used ironically on the occasion of a remarkable action by someone else; fig[uratively], to win a strikingly useless prize for doing something well, to perform a useless action in a superior manner, or doing something well.

An entry for "porcelain hairnet," independent of any longer specific set phrase. appears in Maurice Wesseen, A Dictionary of American Slang (1934), in the "General Slang" category:

Porcelain hairnet—Ironic name of approbation for anything that most people regard as superior.

Wesseen doesn't explain the genesis of "porcelain hairnet" as a slang term in this particular sense, but I don't get the impression that the porcelain part of the expression has any direct connection to toilets. The first slang expression I am aware of that makes that connection explicit is "pray to the porcelain god," which Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, Dictionary of American Slang, third edition (1994) define as follows:

pray to the porcelain god v phr 1970s college students To vomit in the toilet

In the absence of an established equation of "porcelain" with "toilet" in the 1930s, it seems to me, there is little reason to connect "wear the brown helmet" with "win the porcelain hairnet," Alan Axelrod's argument notwithstanding, any more than it connects with the baseball slang expression "wear [or win or get] the golden sombrero"—meaning "to strike out four times in a single game, as suggested in Paul Dickson, The Dickson Baseball Dictionary, third edition (2009):

golden sombrero A mythical award given to a batter who strikes out four times in a game. ... 1ST USE. 1984. "I almost got the Golden Sombrero. That's when you strike out four times. I only got the regular sombrero {hat trick}" (Chicago Cubs first baseman Leon Durham, quoted in Chicago Tribune, Apr. 14.

Despite the strong modern connection in U.S. slang of phrases involving "brown" with allusions to feces, etc., I am not entirely convinced that "wear the brown helmet" has (or originally had) a scatological meaning. Consider this entry from Tom Dalzell & Terry Victor, The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional Englishhttps://books.google.com/books?id=4YfsEgHLjboC&pg=PA272&dq=%22brown+helmet+a+notional+sign%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY_YS-oYCIAxVEGTQIHYcsO7wQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22brown%20helmet%20a%20notional%20sign%22&f=false (2006):

brown helmet a notional sign of one who has been rejected in romance US | Fred Hester, Slang on the 40 Acres, p. 17, 1968

This definition seems adaptable to Axelrod's example from Hill Street Blues in 1981, where a character "characterized the embarrassment of failure as wearing the brown helmet." Although the "brown" here may have a scatological meaning or overtone, I don't think any such implication is unmistakable or necessary. Jonathon Green, [Cassell's Dictionary of Slang], second edition (2005) have an entry for "brown off" that seems similarly ambiguous as to origin:

brown off v. 1 {1930s+} to annoy, to irritate. 2 {1950s} (US) to blunder, to make a mistake. 3 {1960s} (US campus) to reject a request for a date. {[Definition] (1) backform[ation] f[rom] BROWNED OFF adj. [defined elsewhere as in Green's dictionary as "(1930s+} ({orig. milit.) irritated, annoyed. [from] accumulation of brown rust on fatigued or worn-out metal; but note the various uses of BROWN v3 in the context of sodomy"]; subseq[unet] def[inition]s f[rom definition] (1)}

Dalzell & Victor identify Hester and his slang glossary more fully as follows:

Hester Fred[.] Slang on the 40 Acres, Unpublished manuscript, Western Historical Manuscript Collection, Columbia, Missouri, 1968

So all we can say about this source is that it was written in 1968 and currently sits, unpublished, in an archive at the University of Missouri. Still, I think that the 1981 Hill Street Blues use of "wear the brown helmet" is at least as likely to link to "brown helmet" as understood by Fred Hester in 1968 as to "win the porcelain hairnet" as understood by Wentworth & Flexner in 1961 or to "porcelain hairnet" as understood by Wesseen in 1934.

I can't help wondering if there is any link with the UK pejorative term 'brown-hatter'.

The 2011 citation also mentions "porcelain helmet" which has a stronger link to "brown helmet" However, even though I searched low, I searched deep and for long, I did not find any further references to that particular noun phrase.

Has this anything to do with being a coward? The winner of a brown helmet or a porcelain helmet is someone who is so afraid of a battle that they hide themselves -or try to protect themselves-- by ducking their heads in a chamberpot.
